# I have a lot of abc_ files in my resource in my apk file

Tags: android, eclipse

I just started android development but when in eclipse I check there is no extra files in res folder but when I export it and open the res folder in APK I get a lot of extra folders and files in them starting with abc_ and many translations folder created by itself I tried removing it with apktool but it can't compile

anybody can help me to remove these extra abc_ files so that I can create clean apk file

here is pic
http://oi62.tinypic.com/k9ct3b.jpg

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ Dario  i want to remove those abc_bla bla files which are in my every folder like anim created by itself with those files and in many folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it won't compile anymore? Because these files are needed by all kinds of Application elements, the abc_ files are for example used in XML View elements. You should not delete them. I also recommend that when you are new to Android to switch to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) as this is now the official IDE.

Comment: i have android studio but it lags on my laptop and eclipse works smooth thatswhy i prefer eclipse and i didnot added anim folder in resources it got added by itself check this  http://oi62.tinypic.com/k9ct3b.jpg